# What is the paper/pen/dice case used in the PAX Prime 2014 game?

Tags: tools, dice, product-identification

I was looking [the PAX Prime 2014 game](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MLZ_Pl2pApA!) and couldn't help but notice the nice looking cases they have: in the upper portion you can store your character sheet / books, and at the bottom there's a compartment for your dice and pens.

What is this thing called, and where can I buy it online?

(You can see what I mean on the bottom-left corner of the screenshot)

[image: lower half]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The item is an *Officemate slim clipboard storage box.* It's sold [at Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002MCZA2C) for $14.99, and comes in different colors (some of them are discounted, so price varies).

Thanks to @Greenstone Walker, because your answer gave me an idea of the search terms to look for the clipboard in Amazon.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a type of file holder - you can get them from office supply sites like Office Depot or Staples and similar.

You may also find them in stores that carry office or school supplies.  You may also want to look at "portable desks" which tend to have a small box for holding pages, writing utensils as well as a clipboard on the top which is pretty useful.

Also look into art supply websites - there's some hard plastic portfolio cases, art storage boxes and so on that are similar in build but a bit more sturdy.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using a translucent clipboard box, like the ones at [this link](http://www.lynmar.com/shop/clipboards_clear-transparent-box.htm). The one I have doesn't actually have a clipboard insie - just a box. It is thick enough to hold character sheets and dice and pencils. It won't hold rulebooks (well, it might hold just the PHB) but it wil hold the Starter Set books (like LMoP).

The box isn't rigid enough to write on, sadly. I thought it might be when I bought it.

Comment: The asker isn't asking what people use for pen/paper/dice folders, but for an identification of a specific kind of folder.